# Trignometry: Find the value in terms of $ \ l \ $

Tags: trigonometry

If $ \ \tan x + \sec x \ = \ l \ , $
find the value of secant x in terms of $ \ l \ $ .
I do not know how to solve it but i do know that the basic trig identities are involved.
Pls help me!!!

Comment: $$\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = \sin(x)\sec(x)$$
So what you have there is $\sin(x)\sec(x) + \sec(x) = l$.  You can finish from there?

Comment: No I didnt quite get it

Comment: Any time you see Tan or Sec in an equation, your first response should be to make them Sin and Cos. Just a little hint for the future.

Answer (score 4):

$\displaystyle\sec x+\tan x=l\  \ \ \  (1)$
As $\displaystyle \sec ^2x-\tan^2x=1, (\sec x-\tan x)(\sec x+\tan x)=1$

$\displaystyle \sec x-\tan x=\frac1{(\sec x+\tan x)}=\frac1l$

Can you find $\sec x$ from here?

Comment: no i do not undurstand pls explain

Comment: 2 equations 2 variables : you know a+b and a-b can you find a?

Comment: Another way:

$$\sec x+\tan x=\dfrac{\left(\cos\dfrac x2+\sin\dfrac x2\right)^2}{\cos^2\dfrac x2-\sin^2\dfrac x2}=\dfrac{\cos\dfrac x2+\sin\dfrac x2}{\cos\dfrac x2-\sin\dfrac x2}=\dfrac{1+\tan\dfrac x2}{1-\tan\dfrac x2}=\tan\left(\dfrac\pi4+x\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin x=\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\sec^2x}}=\sqrt{\frac{\sec^2x-1}{\sec^2x}}\\\sec x \left(\sqrt{\frac{\sec^2x-1}{\sec^2x}}+1\right)=l\\\sec x=t\\t\sqrt{\frac{t^2-1}{t^2}}=l-t\\t^2\frac{t^2-1}{t^2}=l^2-2lt+t^2\\t^2-1-t^2=l^2-2lt\\2lt=l^2+1\\t=\frac{l^2+1}{2l}$$

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the definitions:
$$\tan x + \sec x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} + \frac{1}{\cos x} = \frac{1 + \sin x}{\cos x}.$$
So we seek $x$ such that
$$1 + \sin x = L \cos x \quad \text{or} \quad L \cos x - \sin x = 1.$$

Let $t = \tan(x/2)$. Then
$$\sin x = 2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = 2\frac{\sin(x/2)}{\cos(x/2)}\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = 2\frac{\tan(x/2)}{\sec^2(x/2)} = \color{red}{\frac{2t}{1 + t^2}}.$$

Similarly,
$$\cos x = \cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) - \sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = \cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\left(1 - \frac{\sin^2(x/2)}{\cos^2(x/2)}\right) = \frac{1 - \tan^2(x/2)}{\sec^2(x/2)} = \color{red}{\frac{1 - t^2}{1 + t^2}}.$$

To obtain the expressions in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ just draw a right triangle with angle $= x/2$.

Therefore, $L \cos x - \sin x = 1$ transforms into
$$L\frac{1 - t^2}{1 + t^2} - \frac{2t}{1 + t^2} - 1 = 0.$$

If you solve for $t$ you should get $t = -1$ or $t = (L - 1)/(L + 1)$. So
$$x = -\frac{\pi}{2} \quad \text{or} \quad x = 2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{L - 1}{L + 1}\right).$$
Clearly, $x \ne -\pi/2$ because $\cos(-\pi/2) = 0$, so
$$x = 2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{L - 1}{L + 1}\right), \quad L \ne -1.$$

Comment: the solution is L not 1 and we need to find sec in terms of L

Comment: The question is pretty hard

Comment: @user132417 L? I thought it was $1$.

Comment: But the options are as follows-

Comment: L-1, 1+l^2 ,L^2+ 1/2L, (L^2+1)/2L

Comment: @user132417 I will edit my answer.